# Checking type with template C++

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, sfinae, decltype

I'm studying the implementation of the `Matrix` class (explained in Stroustrup's book TC++PL 4th ed.), but I can't really understand some passages.

I found this code:

file traits.h -> https://github.com/statslabs/matrix/blob/master/include/slab/matrix/traits.h

file matrix.h -> https://github.com/statslabs/matrix/blob/master/include/slab/matrix/matrix.h

In matrix.h there is a function (as many other) with `Enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
template<typename M, typename F>
Enable_if<Matrix_type<M>(), Matrix<T, N> &> Matrix<T, N>::apply(const M &m, F f) {
    /// Some code...
}
```

and I think `Enable_if` says: If (`M` is a `Matrix`), declare the apply's return type as `Matrix<T, N>&`.

Then, I want to know how does `Matrix_type<M>()` works, so I go to `traits.h`, and I read:

```
struct substitution_failure {};

template <typename T>
struct substitution_succeeded : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct substitution_succeeded<substitution_failure> : std::false_type {};

template <typename M>
struct get_matrix_type_result {
  template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
  static bool check(const Matrix<T, N> &m);

  template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
  static bool check(const MatrixRef<T, N> &m);

  static substitution_failure check(...);

  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<M>()));
};

template <typename T>
struct has_matrix_type
    : substitution_succeeded<typename get_matrix_type_result<T>::type> {};

template <typename M>
constexpr bool Has_matrix_type() {
  return has_matrix_type<M>::value;
}

template <typename M>
using Matrix_type_result = typename get_matrix_type_result<M>::type;

template <typename M>
constexpr bool Matrix_type() {
  return Has_matrix_type<M>();
}
```

The first 3 structs describe success and failure cases, the `template<>` is the specialization of `substitution_succeeded` that says: if the type of `substitution_succeeded` is `substitution_failure`, "return" false else "return" true.
I hope that what I'm saying is correct.

Now, `get_matrix_type_result` is completely obscure. I can't understand why it use a variadic function (`check(...)`), what are `declval` and `decltype` doing in this code and how it is possible that check can return a bool or a `substitution_failure`. Why not just `bool`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, get_matrix_type_result is completely obscure. I can't understand why it use a variadic function (check(...)), what are declval and decltype doing in this code and how it is possible that check can return a bool or a "substitution_failure". Why not just bool?

An important point is that `Enable_if` (`std::enable_if` starting from C++11) is designed to enable or not enable something (a template function, a template class specialization, a template method, a template variable specialization).

On the ground is a C++ principle named SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) that say that, in some places, if a substitution do not take place, it's only a soft error, non an hard error, and the compilation can continue.

In your case, you have that `type` is defined as follows

```
using type = decltype(check(std::declval<M>()));
```

where `decltype()` "return" the type of the argument; in this case, the type returned from a call to `check()` with an hypothetical object of type `M` (the template parameter of the class).

You could write

```
using type = decltype(check(M{}));
```

to pass an object of type `M`. But this works only with types that are default constructible. The question is: how to use, in a `decltype()` argument (that has the exclusive function to deduce types, not execute instructions) an object of a generic type if we don't know how construct an object of that type?

The solution is a function only declared (not defined) as follows

```
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

This is a trick to have an object of type `T` (or better: `T &`) also when do you don't know how to construct it.

Returning to `check`, you have three version of it (only declared: are used inside a `decltype()`; we are only interested in the returned type so there is no need to execute them, so there is no need to define them):

1) the first one accept a `Matrix<T, N>` but **only** (`Enable_if`) if `N >= 1`

```
template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
static bool check(const Matrix<T, N> &m);
```

If you call `check()` with a `Matrix<T, 0>`, the `Enable_if` return nothing so you have a substitution failure (defining the default for a template parameter) so this version of `check()` isn't enabled

2) the second one accept a `MatrixRef<T, N>` but **only** (`Enable_if`) if `N >= 1`

```
template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
static bool check(const MatrixRef<T, N> &m);
```

Again: if you call `check()` with a `MatrixRef<T, 0>`, the `Enable_if` return nothing so you have a substitution failure (defining the default for a template parameter) so this version of `check()` isn't enabled

3) the third one accept everything and is **ever** **enabled**

```
static substitution_failure check(...);
```

Conclusion:

1) if `M` is a `Matrix<T, N>` (or an object convertible to a `Matrix<T, N>`), for some `T` and some `N` with `N >= 1`, the compiler can choose between version (1) and version (3) of `check()` and choose version (1) because more specialized, that return `bool`, so `type` become `bool`

2) if `M` is a `MatrixRef<T, N>` (or an object convertible to a `MatrixRef<T, N>`), for some `T` and some `N` with `N >= 1`, the compiler can choose between version (2) and version (3) of `check()` and choose version (2) because more specialized, that return `bool`, so `type` become `bool`

3) if `M` isn't convertible to a `Matrix<T, N>` or a `MatrixRef<T, N>`, with `N >= 1`, the compiler can choose only version (3), that return a `substitution_failure`, so `type` become `substitution_failure`.

Off Topic: the code you show us seems to me a little overcomplicated.

By example, if you rewrite `get_matrix_type_result` as follows

```
template <typename M>
struct get_matrix_type_result {
  template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
  static std::true_type check(const Matrix<T, N> &m);

  template <typename T, size_t N, typename = Enable_if<(N >= 1)>>
  static std::true_type check(const MatrixRef<T, N> &m);

  static std::false_type check(...);

  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<M>()));
};
```

you have that `type` is the type that you needs in `has_matrix_type` that can be defined as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct has_matrix_type
    : public get_matrix_type_result<T>::type
 { };
```

avoiding at all `substitution_failure` and `substitution_succeded`.

But, maybe, the code is written this way for other needs.

Comment: I got all of it! thank you very very very much. About the code, I don't know why it is written so complicated, I'm just a student, I don't have a professional background of C++ (i'm trying to learn it). The book says that it is a good practice to "mask" the code (without put too many level of abstraction) so that user doesn't see implementation's detail and because is more scalable. I don't know, maybe it is because if you want to implements an exception or some code you can do it in substitution_failure or substitution_succeded and not in std::true_type or std::false_type.